# Is full width carousel possible?

Tags: carousel, jssor

I would like to make the Jssor Carousel full width, without resizing height at all when the window resizes. So on a wide screen, it would show more slides and on a narrow screen it will show less, without ever changing height. I don't want the slider to resize, I just want it to cut off, if that makes sense.

So far I've got it working as I'd like in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera. If I'm not explaining it very well, I apologize, you can see an example of how I'd like it to work here: http://jessetessman.com/110/slider.php in Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera. Note, when you resize the window you have to refresh to resize the slider.

My problem is, it doesn't work in IE. It just has a width of 100px in IE and I have no idea how to get it working.

I appreciate any help you can give. I realize the way I have it now is probably not the best way to go about accomplishing this, but I am not very good with javascript so I just messed with it until I got to this point. Any suggestions about better ways to do this are certainly welcome.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add one line $("#news-slider").width("100%");

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("news-slider", options);
        $("#news-slider").width("100%");
```

Forgot to change following css, make the width to greater than screen width then.

```
#news-slider {
    left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 2400px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;
}
#news-slider .slides {
    left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 2400px; height: 350px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've done what you suggested and it seems to have fixed half the problem, but it is still not working yet. The #news-slider div is now at 100% width, but the div just inside that one is still set to 100px wide, and since it doesn't have a class or id, I can't apply the same solution to it. I haven't been able to figure out how to add a class or id to it. Perhaps you can help me with this?

Comment: Thank you so much, that works! It does cause the right arrow navigation to disappear off the page, but thats not a big issue, I'll just remove the arrow nav altogether. It also doesn't work in IE 8 and down, but this is also not a big issue for me, I'll just not display the slider for IE 8 and lower. I appreciate the help and the great slider!

Comment: You can set $Scale to false for $ArrowNavigatorOptions to prevent arrow from hiding.